# We have the same size, yet we are different

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

The answer to this puzzle is one that makes sense. Good Luck!

---

[image]

---

For the colorblind:

**Left** grid (in order, row by row)-

(GV)(G)(Y)(B)(O)

(R)(RY)(I)

(O)

(B)

(V)(I)

**Right** grid (in order, row by row)-

(B)(O)

(YV)(G)(R)

(I)(G)

(I)

(O)(R)

(Y)

(V)

(B)

Colored dashes, in order (top to bottom):

B

R

G

Y

O

V

I

Comment: Is blue missing a blank? And I am assuming blue is at the bottom.

Comment: @Amoz I was just going to ask the same - although it could equally be Yellow that's missing a blank... (unless you've worked out something further than I have to narrow it down further already...!)

Comment: @Amoz Blue is not missing a blank. I've added info on the colors.

Comment: @Stiv Likewise, yellow isn't missing a blank

Comment: I don't know how much progress you guys have made, but the dashes should make sense if everything else is correct

Comment: @Prim3numbah Have to be honest - I've sussed the first vowels section, realised part of their importance to the next but not yet worked out how to read the grid. However, I noticed that the dashed sections were rot13(nyzbfg gur fnzr yratguf nf gur anzrf bs gur frira qnlf bs gur jrrx, jvgu bar qnfu zvffvat) and so I was punting on there potentially being a typo which might help me *back*-solve the middle part! No dice though - gonna have to go the long way round :)

Comment: @Stiv Aaah, that's completely coincidental then :) Once you get the vowels part fully figured out, the grid will hopefully make more sense.

Comment: I have the grid done and got a bunch of good info, but if the dashes aren't days if the week then I am running into too many alternate options to try, none of which are working, to do the bottom.

Comment: @Amoz Ok. Yes the dashes are not days of the week. Hmm, it's hard to guide you without really seeing your progress. But you should focus solely on the how to make sense of what the grids represent (since you understood how to interpret the dots in the grids correctly, if I understood you right?) and not focus on the dashes (for now)

Comment: @Prim3numbah Okay I think I finally found which path works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to the puzzle is the word:

> DOLLARS

Reasoning:

Top section:
Here there a bunch of vowels formed by

> Removing consonants from the months of the year and from the numerical digits 0-9:
>  [image: vowels]

Middle Section:

> Here we use the arrows to align the months left to right (Jan - Dec) and the digits top to bottom (0 - 9) to get two sets of dates.  For example, here the green dots represent January 1 1 or January 11:
>  [image: dots]

> January 11 is conveniently the birthday of Alexander Hamilton, and the green dots on calendar #2 show July 12, the day of death for Alexander Hamilton.  ALEXANDER fits into the green blanks below the grid.
>  So each calendar represents the birth and death of, it turns out, a person who appears on one of the U.S. dollar bills, each showing the SAME figure but a DIFFERENT point in their life (birth - death). Although as @MOehm has discovered, a much better observation is that the DOLLAR BILLS themselves are each the same (physical) size but different (denomination)!
>  Continuing, the blanks are easily filled in with either a first or last name:
>  [image: figures]

Turning to the boxed letters, these spell from top to bottom:

> DOLLARS, and the rainbow order gives the order of each figure on a dollar bill:

> RED: George Washington 1$

> ORANGE: Thomas Jefferson, 2$

> YELLOW: Abraham Lincoln, 5$

> GREEN: Alexander Hamilton, 10$

> BLUE: Andrew Jackson, 20$

> INDIGO: Ulysses Grant, 50$

> VIOLET: Benjamin Franklin, 100$

Also I don't know if this was intentional, but I had also noticed that "The answer to this puzzle is one that makes sense".  Well,

> Dollars do make cents ; )

Comment: Well done :) You're so close on your reasoning at the end, except... rot13(Gurfr nera'g nyy Cerfvqragf - Unzvygba naq Senaxyva arire qvq yrnq gur pbhagel - ohg gurl ner nyy svtherf ba HF ONAXABGRF, urapr lbhe nafjre!) In fact, rainbow order gives you [the exact sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_dollar#Banknotes)...

Comment: yes I just realized that

Comment: Yes, well done. And the title makes the answer stand out from similar designs.

Comment: @MOehm Aha good point I'll edit that in and credit you! I forgot about double checking the title after I realized the issue w/ the presidents.

Comment: Yes, the title if often a blind spot. (No need to credit me, really. You did all the heavy solving.)

Comment: Great job! Everything looks good. Also. although not intentional, nice with the wordplay at the end :)